# Google Sheets hyperlinks - opening multiple URLs in a new browser tab each time - without the use of popups

Tags: google-apps-script, browser, hyperlink

I have a spreadsheet which has a list of website URLS.
The google sheet runs a script that when you select/highlight multiple cells and then click the 'open selected hyperlinks' button the list of selected URLs is opened in a new browser tab each time.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FIFywGyt5SPrvl1z-V01JU1fMQRd1E0yIXETs4w7Ufs/edit?usp=sharing

Is it possible to adapt the script so that this will work in a browser where 'popups' are switched off?

This is the script as currently:

```
function openAllLinks() {
  // Get the selected range
  const selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();

  // Filter for cells containing hyperlinks
  const withLinks = selection.getRichTextValues()
    .flatMap(row => row.flatMap(cellRichTextValue => {
      const links = cellRichTextValue.getRuns().filter(run => run.getLinkUrl());
      return links.length > 0 ? links[0].getLinkUrl() : [];
    }));

  if (withLinks.length == 0) {
    Browser.msgBox("No URLs were found.");
    return;
  }
  const opens = withLinks.map(url => `window.open('${url}', '_blank');`).join("");
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<html><script>${opens};google.script.host.close();    </script></html>`);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
  // ---
```

// Show a confirmation message
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Links opened successfully!');
}

Kind regards,
Matt

I am not a coder and have very limited knowledge so have tried to research this as much as I can!

Comment: I believe preventing `popups` is a security feature of the browser, not Google App Script.

Comment: hi, thanks, yes it is..but this is for a chrome based platform where popups are switched off..

Comment: You need to disable it with the browser.  There are no App Script function to do that.